# Loading data into the current div

Tags: php, jquery

I have two divs, and when one is clicked it empties the div. I want to be able to load data into that div once it's been emptied. I've got it so it loads in both, but I only want to load data into the div that's been emptied.

**HTML (I have two of these)**

```
<div class="fl person">
    <div class="maintain_size">
        <input type="hidden" name="userSaved" value="<?php echo $user_one['id']; ?>" />
            <img src="<?php echo "http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_one['id']."/picture?type=large"; ?>" class="circle-mask"  />
            <img class="hoverimage" src="images/fire_extinguisher.png" />
            <div class="meta_data">
                <h2><?php echo $user_one['name']; ?></h2>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$("div.person img").click(function () {
        $(this).parent("div").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        var saved_id_user_who_voted_val = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";
        var saved_id_user_voted_on_val = $(this).parent('div').find('input:hidden');
        var saved_id_user_voted_on_val = saved_id_user_voted_on_val.val();

        $(this).parent("div").empty();

        // Load in new data
        var current_div = $(this).parent("div");
        $.get('loadNewUser.php', function(data) {
          current_div.html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The data seems to come through fine if I select a div that's not the current one, or I just use an alert to see if the data is there--which it is, but if I try load the data into the current div it just doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

**The code that I think is wrong:**

```
$.get('loadNewUser.php', function(data) {
      current_div.html(data);
});
```

**Edit:** The div I'm trying to get the data into is: div.person - although, there are 2 of these.

Comment: where it is the instance of current div?

Comment: The div is: div.person - although, there are 2 of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you empty the div your 'this' is no longer there. Try just declaring var current_div before you empty.

```
var current_div = $(this).parent("div");
current_div.empty();
$.get('loadNewUser.php', function(data) {
      current_div.html(data);
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z2zz/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event as you are replacing old content with new one

```
$(document.body).on('click',"div.person img",function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use live() function
Example

```
$("div.person img").live("click",function () {
//Your code goes here
});
```